# Creating a complete list of valid paths via recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, path-finding

I have a table of with ids & their neighbors and need to create a recursive function that finds **all possible paths** from the start id to the end id without crossing the the same points twice. Lets assume the start id is 1 and the end id is 3.

```
{1 | 2,5}
{2 | 1,3,4,5}
{3 | 2,5}
{4 | 2}
{5 | 1,2,3}
```

This current snippet written by [@Jeffrey Phillips Freeman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5028702/jeffrey-phillips-freeman) worked pretty well, except that it only returns one possible path instead of all the possible paths which would be (1,2,3) & (1,5,3). I've been advised that an A* algorithm would work best for this situation, but I would still like to create the list of valid paths that take me from point A to B without going that route. The new snippet would need to simply place **all** the valid paths in an ArrayList. I intend to use the ArrayList to determine the best path by considering both the path length as well as other factors. So an ArrayList sorted by path distance would be a bonus. As an added note the nodes in the actual problem have spatial coordinates attached to them, however the path between nodes are not always straight lines.

```
List<Integer> searchHops(int from, int to, List<Integer> seen) {
    seen.add(from);

    if (from == to)
        return new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(from));

    for (int neighbor : getNeighbors(from))

        if (!seen.contains(neighbor)) {
            List<Integer> result = searchHops(neighbor, to, seen);

            if (result != null) {
                result.add(0, from);
                return result;
            }
        }

    return null;
}
```

I have about 200 points and in it's current state, a simple test from point A to point B (only one point away) takes me on a 22 hop journey.

Comment: Why don't you want to use A\*?

Comment: @ruakh I was given this https://github.com/Syncleus/dANN-core/blob/v2.x/src/main/java/com/syncleus/dann/graph/search/pathfinding/AstarPathFinder.java but it seems a bit too complicated for something of this miniature scale.

Comment: What exactly is your expectation here? Are you asking us to rewrite the code to do what you want?  If this is an assignment, how will that help you learn?  The point is for you to do the work yourself.  Do the many descriptions of Dijkstra on the web not help?

Comment: @JimGarrison This isn't an assignment, but rather a simple Java project that I made complicated because it seemed too easy.

Comment: You can easily modify my code to return all paths if you just dont let it terminate the for loop early. Instead let it collect each valid result into a list of lists and return that....

Comment: @royjr By the way everyone in the commentws is correct, you still want A* since as you expressed in the last question you want all the paths but you want them sorted from shortest to longest. A* provides this.

Comment: By the way he also left out some important details, like the edges he is dealing with are weighted.

Comment: @Jeffrey I'm not sure what you mean by weighted.

Comment: @royjr weighted means there is a "Cost" associated with traversing from one node to the next. A typical example would be the actual length of a road that connect two waypoints. When we talk about shortest path we basically mean "least cost"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify my original code to return all paths as a List just as you requested. Just dont have the code return early. This will not sort by path length, however, If you want that then you need A*.

```
public List<List<Integer>> searchHops(int from, int to, Set<Integer> seen) {
    seen.add(from);

    if (from == to) {
        final List<List<Integer>> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        newList.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(from)));
        return newList;
    }

    List<List<Integer>> allPaths = null;
    for (int neighbor : getNeighbors(from)) {
        if (!seen.contains(neighbor)) {
            List<List<Integer>> results = searchHops(neighbor, to, new HashSet<>(seen));

            if (results != null) {
                for(List<Integer> result : results) {
                    result.add(0, from);
                    if( allPaths != null )
                        allPaths.add(result);
                }
                if( allPaths == null )
                    allPaths = results;
            }
        }
    }
    return allPaths;
}
```

**If you actually care about ordering your paths from shortest path to longest path then it would be far better to use A***. A* will return as many of the possible paths as you want in order of shortest path first. So if what you really want are all possible paths ordered from shortest to longest then you still want the A* algorithm. The code I suggested above would be much slower than it needs to be if you care about ordering from shortest to longest, not to mention would take up more space then you'd want in order to store every possible path at once.

Since you indicated you cared about shortest path first, and may want to retrieve N-shortest paths then you absolutely should be using A* here.

If you want an A* based implementation capable of returning all paths ordered from the shortest to the longest, the following will accomplish that. It has several advantages. First off it is efficient at sorting from shortest to longest. Also it computes each additional path only when needed, so if you stop early because you dont need every single path you save some processing time. It also reuses data for subsequent paths each time it calculates the next path so it is more efficient. Overall should be the most efficient algorithm if you care about sorting by path length.

```
import java.util.*;

public class AstarSearch {
    private final Map<Integer, Set<Neighbor>> adjacency;
    private final int destination;

    private final NavigableSet<Step> pending = new TreeSet<>();

    public AstarSearch(Map<Integer, Set<Neighbor>> adjacency, int source, int destination) {
        this.adjacency = adjacency;
        this.destination = destination;

        this.pending.add(new Step(source, null, 0));
    }

    public List<Integer> nextShortestPath() {
        Step current = this.pending.pollFirst();
        while( current != null) {
            if( current.getId() == this.destination )
                return current.generatePath();
            for (Neighbor neighbor : this.adjacency.get(current.id)) {
                if(!current.seen(neighbor.getId())) {
                    final Step nextStep = new Step(neighbor.getId(), current, current.cost + neighbor.cost + predictCost(neighbor.id, this.destination));
                    this.pending.add(nextStep);
                }
            }
            current = this.pending.pollFirst();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected int predictCost(int source, int destination) {
        return 0; //Behaves identical to Dijkstra's algorithm, override to make it A*
    }

    private static class Step implements Comparable<Step> {
        final int id;
        final Step parent;
        final int cost;

        public Step(int id, Step parent, int cost) {
            this.id = id;
            this.parent = parent;
            this.cost = cost;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public Step getParent() {
            return parent;
        }

        public int getCost() {
            return cost;
        }

        public boolean seen(int node) {
            if(this.id == node)
                return true;
            else if(parent == null)
                return false;
            else
                return this.parent.seen(node);
        }

        public List<Integer> generatePath() {
            final List<Integer> path;
            if(this.parent != null)
                path = this.parent.generatePath();
            else
                path = new ArrayList<>();
            path.add(this.id);
            return path;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Step step) {
            if(step == null)
                return 1;
            if( this.cost != step.cost)
                return Integer.compare(this.cost, step.cost);
            if( this.id != step.id )
                return Integer.compare(this.id, step.id);
            if( this.parent != null )
                this.parent.compareTo(step.parent);
            if(step.parent == null)
                return 0;
            return -1;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Step step = (Step) o;
            return id == step.id &&
                cost == step.cost &&
                Objects.equals(parent, step.parent);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(id, parent, cost);
        }
    }

   /*******************************************************
   *   Everything below here just sets up your adjacency  *
   *   It will just be helpful for you to be able to test *
   *   It isnt part of the actual A* search algorithm     *
   ********************************************************/

    private static class Neighbor {
        final int id;
        final int cost;

        public Neighbor(int id, int cost) {
            this.id = id;
            this.cost = cost;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public int getCost() {
            return cost;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Map<Integer, Set<Neighbor>> adjacency = createAdjacency();
        final AstarSearch search = new AstarSearch(adjacency, 1, 4);
        System.out.println("printing all paths from shortest to longest...");
        List<Integer> path = search.nextShortestPath();
        while(path != null) {
            System.out.println(path);
            path = search.nextShortestPath();
        }
    }

    private static Map<Integer, Set<Neighbor>> createAdjacency() {
        final Map<Integer, Set<Neighbor>> adjacency = new HashMap<>();

        //This sets up the adjacencies. In this case all adjacencies have a cost of 1, but they dont need to. Otherwise
        //They are exactly the same as the example you gave in your question
        addAdjacency(adjacency, 1,2,1,5,1);         //{1 | 2,5}
        addAdjacency(adjacency, 2,1,1,3,1,4,1,5,1); //{2 | 1,3,4,5}
        addAdjacency(adjacency, 3,2,1,5,1);         //{3 | 2,5}
        addAdjacency(adjacency, 4,2,1);             //{4 | 2}
        addAdjacency(adjacency, 5,1,1,2,1,3,1);     //{5 | 1,2,3}

        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(adjacency);
    }

    private static void addAdjacency(Map<Integer, Set<Neighbor>> adjacency, int source, Integer... dests) {
        if( dests.length % 2 != 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("dests must have an equal number of arguments, each pair is the id and cost for that traversal");

        final Set<Neighbor> destinations = new HashSet<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < dests.length; i+=2)
            destinations.add(new Neighbor(dests[i], dests[i+1]));
        adjacency.put(source, Collections.unmodifiableSet(destinations));
    }
}
```

The output from the above code is the following:

```
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 5, 2, 4]
[1, 5, 3, 2, 4]
```

Notice that each time you call `nextShortestPath()` it generates the next shortest path for you on demand. It only calculates the extra steps needed and doesnt traverse any old paths twice. Moreover if you decide you dont need all the paths and end exeuction early you've saved yourself considerable computation time. You only compute up to the number of paths you need and no more.

If you have some sort of a heuristic that helps you estimate path cost then override the `predictCost()` method and put it there. You mentioned that your nodes also have spatial coordinates associated with them. A good heuristic in this case would be the euclidean distance between the two nodes (the distance a straight line between them would be). It is however entirely option and only helps improve computation time if you exit before computing all possible paths.

Finally it should be noted that the A* and Dijkstra algorithms do have some minor limitations, though I dont think it would effect you. Namely it will not work right on a graph that has negative weights.

Here is a link to JDoodle where you can run the code yourself in the browser and see it working. You can also change around the graph to show it works on other graphs as well: http://jdoodle.com/a/ukx

Comment: Try adding a link from 1 to 4 (the line becomes `addAdjacency(adjacency, 1,2,1,5,1,4,1);`). The 1-2-4 solution is no longer found.

Comment: Or if the line is `addAdjacency(adjacency, 1,2,1,4,1,5,1);` then it only finds 1-4.

Comment: But if it's `addAdjacency(adjacency, 1,4,1,2,1,5,1);1 then it finds all of them.

Comment: @sprinter Thanks for catching that. I just fixed the bug and edited my answer. It should work perfectly now.

Comment: yep that seemed to work. I compared the two solutions for a graph with 17 nodes, 8 links per node, and 2,126,061 solutions. Both solutions gave the exact same results. The exhaustive then sort solution took 2132 ms and the A* solution took 7708 ms. That included simplifying your solution to get rid of the neighbour class (given all links had cost 1 anyway). I can send you all the code I used if you want to take a look.

Comment: @sprinter A* would be superior only when you calculate in the cost to sort by path length. Did you sort by path length with your code? If you use your code to get all paths, then sort the path length, your solution would be considerably slower. The advantage of my solution is that it automatically sorts by shortest path first with no additional costs. Which is exactly what the OP needed.

Comment: Yes I added the sort by path length. It is almost instant: sorting 2M integers is a very very fast operation in Java. The advantage of the exhaustive solution is the sort is only performed once.

Comment: @sprinter sure, share your benchmark code, I'd love to see it. I'd also be curious about space optimization as well, though I understand if you havent tested for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170136/discussion-between-sprinter-and-jeffrey-phillips-freeman).

Comment: @JeffreyPhillipsFreeman Interesting.. how would I add a list of integers using addAdjacency like addAdjacency(adjacency, arrayList)?

Comment: @JeffreyPhillipsFreeman the closest I was able to get was the following  `addAdjacency(adjacency, nnn.get(0),nnn.get(1),nnn.get(2),nnn.get(3),nnn.get(4));`

Comment: @royjr to add an adjacency you do `addAdjacency(map, sourceId, destination1Id, cost1Id, destination2Id, cost2Id, defination3Id, cost3Id...)` Cost would be the distance of the road represented by the edge, or the difficulty in traversing it or similar. If you dont care about any of that set it to 1.

Comment: Use a bad hack.. but it works! `if (nnn.size() == 3) { addAdjacency(adjacency, nnn.get(0), nnn.get(1), nnn.get(2)); } else if (nnn.size() == 5) {` and so on. LOTS OF PATHS.. almost too much `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`

Comment: @royjr that "hack" wont really work. you need to add the adjacency cost after each adjacency... use 1 if you dont have a meaningful cost. Also what is nnn exactly.. look at the example i show examples of how to add adjacencies based off your adjacency int he OP.. it goes "destination, weight" alternating back and forth. weight means the same thing as cost here.

Comment: @royjr a line like this `addAdjacency(foo, 1,2,1,3,1,4,1)` says: there is a adjacency from 1 to 2 with a weight/cost of 1, there is a adjacency from 1 to 3 with a cost of 1, there is a adjacency from 1 to 4 with a cost of 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170174/discussion-between-royjr-and-jeffrey-phillips-freeman).

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason at all to use A*. It is designed to find the shortest path as efficiently as possible. Given you want to find all paths irrespective of length A* will be overhead with no benefit.

In pseduocode your algorithm should look something like:

```
findPaths for path:
    if path is complete
        add to solution set
    else
        for each link from last step that is not in path
            add next step to path
            call findPaths
            remove next step from path
```

At the moment you are returning a path. If you want to find all paths then you need to store it in a list of paths.

Here is an example implementation:

```
public class FindPath {
    private final Stack<Integer> path = new Stack<>();
    private final Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> links = new HashMap<>();

    public void addLink(int from, int to) {
        links.putIfAbsent(from, new HashSet<>());
        links.get(from).add(to);
    }

    public void find(int from, int to, Consumer<Stack<Integer>> action) {
        path.push(from);
        if (from == to)
            action.accept(path);
        else
            links.getOrDefault(from, Set.of()).stream()
                    .filter(s -> !path.contains(s))
                    .forEach(s -> find(s, to, action));
        path.pop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FindPath finder = new FindPath();
        Random rand = new Random();
        IntStream.range(0, 20).forEach(n -> rand.ints(7, 0, 20).forEach(t -> finder.addLink(n, t)));
        finder.find(0, 19, System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. thats what I figured

Comment: A* can find the shortest path OR the nth-shortest path. If you want to find the 10 shortest paths, for example, then A* still makes sense. If you always want to find all paths, then there isnt as much of an advantage. @royjr it really just boils down to if you always need ALL the paths or if you really just need a subset of the paths ordered by distance.

Comment: I should add that even if you want to find ALL paths A* is still the best choice if you want those paths ordered from shortest to longest. Only time A* really has no advantage is if you want all the paths and don't are about ordering.

Comment: @JeffreyPhillipsFreeman do you have any evidence for that assertion? I find it incredibly unlikely that A* would be of any advantage over a single sort by path cost after all solutions are found. And it increases the complexity of implementation over a unsorted exhaustive search.

Comment: @sprinter I could probably find something easy enough. But considering it can be written ina  dozen or two lines I'm not sure I agree that it is considerably complexity. I've re-written the algorithm many times in my career and it has never taken more than a few minutes. The real question you need to ask is can you think of an algorithm that can do it faster or at the same time, and do you have references for that?

Comment: @JeffreyPhillipsFreeman please do. I'd be interested to see what you'd use as your heuristic function given the nodes are position less. In any case I've added a simple implementation of an exhaustive search for you to compare.

Comment: @sprinter I've added to my answer below an A* implementation that specifically solves his problem. Should be evident from the implementation why it is more efficient. Sadly what he left out from his question this time is that he does care about sorting it by path length. Which would make your algorithm inefficient in that regard.

Comment: @sprinter The nodes arent position less. He just did a very poor job wording his question. They have spatial coordinates. With that said an A* with a heuristic of 0 works just fine, it then becomes a dijkstra algorithm. Which is still more efficient at ordering by path length.

Comment: @JeffreyPhillipsFreeman no it's still broken. Try moving the last call to `addAdjacency` to the start and you'll find you only get 2 solutions. I suggest you remove the answer and do some debugging then repost.

Comment: @sprinter I just tried that, no bug, my code still executed and gave the exact same, correct, output. See for yourself: http://jdoodle.com/a/ukx That code has the edit you suggested, runs fine and still gives proper output. You can execute it at the link provided.